# Find all automorphism for the complex set

Tags: complex-analysis, automorphism-group

> Let $B=\{z \in \mathbb C:0<\operatorname{Im} z<\pi\}$. Find all holomorphic automorphisms of $B$.

I can see what the set $B$ looks like, but I don't know how to find the automorphisms, and since there is no general method to find them, I am lost on how to solve the proble, in particular because it asks for ALL the automorphisms.

I thought of having some Moebius transformation do the job, or maybe I should be looking at big Picard's theorem?

Comment: What are $x, y, z$? Are they constants or variables, real or complex? Is $B \subset \mathbb C ^3$? Are the automorphisms required to be holomorphic?

Comment: @lisyarus $x,y$ are constants, thus $z$ is complex. $B\subset \mathbb{C}^2$. Yes, the automorphims need to be holomorphic.

Comment: I think you mean that $x,y$ are real variables, and that $B \subset \mathbb C$. Is this right? (if $x,y$ are constants, the question doesn't make much sense: the set $B$ is either empty or has a single point, depending on whether $0 \le y \le \pi$).

Comment: I've changed the wording in the question. Please, check that I didn't change the meaning of it.

Comment: As for the answer: use the Riemann mapping theorem to map $B$ to the unit circle, and find automorphisms of the unit circle using the strong version of the mapping theorem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem, "Henri Poincaré proved that the map f is essentially unique...")

Comment: @lisyarus Can you explain how the new statement is the same as before? From what I understood the set $B$ was supposed to be something like this https://i.imgur.com/gRHY4eo.jpg (apologies my inabilities to draw).

I'm not sure I follow your suggestion. Wouldn't I still have to find ALL holomorphims from the unit circle to $B$?